# Program not working right on other windows machines

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt5, qt-creator

I'm having a problem with my application, in which I'm trying to get all network configurations of the system that it runs on. The final goal is to find the MAC address with highest priority.

The code runs ok and works when I run it with QtCreator and also runs ok when I create a folder containing the dll files and the exe file.

But the problem is that when I run this program on other windows machines (7 and 10) it runs but does not return or show anything. I tried running it as an Administrator, that didn't work neither and this code should be able to work on all windows platforms.

Any suggestions?

I'm currently on **Windows 10** and using **Qt 5.8 MSVC 2015**

The exe file runs with these dlls on Windows 10:

- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Network.dll
- msvcp140.dll
- msvcr120.dll
- vcruntime140.dll

These dlls should be also there for windows 7:

- api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
- api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
- api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
- api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
- api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll

Link below is the exe and dll files together:

https://ufile.io/e9htu

here's my code if needed:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "macfinder.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MACFinder macFinder;
    macFinder.findMAC();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**macfinder.h**

```
#ifndef MACFINDER_H
#define MACFINDER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkConfiguration>
#include <QNetworkConfigurationManager>
#include <QNetworkInterface>
#include <QNetworkSession>
#include <QDebug>

class MACFinder : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MACFinder(QObject *parent = 0);
    void findMAC();
private:
    QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
    QString filterMAC(QList<QNetworkConfiguration> configs);

signals:
    void foundMAC(QString MAC);
private slots:
    void configurationsUpdateCompleted();
};

#endif // MACFINDER_H
```

**macfinder.cpp**

```
#include "macfinder.h"

MACFinder::MACFinder(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

QString MACFinder::filterMAC(QList<QNetworkConfiguration> configs)
{
    qDebug() << "MAC and Index: ";
    QString MAC;
    int index;
    QNetworkConfiguration nc;
    foreach(nc,configs)
    {
        QNetworkSession networkSession(nc);
        QNetworkInterface netInterface = networkSession.interface();
        QString debugStr = QString::number(netInterface.index())
                + " | " + netInterface.humanReadableName() + " | "
                + nc.name() + " | " + netInterface.hardwareAddress();
        if(netInterface.hardwareAddress().isEmpty())
        {
            qDebug() << "--> No MAC: " << debugStr;
            continue;
        }
        if(netInterface.name().isEmpty())
        {
            qDebug() << "--> NO NAME: " << debugStr;
            continue;
        }
        if(netInterface.index() == 0)
        {
            qDebug() << "--> NO INDEX: " << debugStr;
            continue;
        }
        if(netInterface.flags() & QNetworkInterface::IsLoopBack)
        {
            qDebug() << "--> loopBack: " << debugStr;
            continue;
        }
        if(netInterface.flags() & (QNetworkInterface::IsRunning | QNetworkInterface::IsUp))
        {
            qDebug() << "*** Accepted: " << debugStr;
            if(MAC.isEmpty())
            {
                qDebug() << "setting MAC:" << debugStr;
                MAC = netInterface.hardwareAddress();
                index = netInterface.index();
            }
            else
            {
                if(netInterface.index() < index)
                {
                    qDebug() << "setting MAC:" << debugStr;
                    MAC = netInterface.hardwareAddress();
                    index = netInterface.index();
                }
                else
                    qDebug() << "index is not lower: " << debugStr;
            }
        }
    }
    return MAC;
}

void MACFinder::findMAC()
{
    qDebug() << "MACFinder::findMAC | updating all configurations";
    connect(&ncm,SIGNAL(updateCompleted()),this,SLOT(configurationsUpdateCompleted()));
    ncm.updateConfigurations();
}

void MACFinder::configurationsUpdateCompleted()
{
    qDebug() << "MACFinder::configurationsUpdateCompleted";
    disconnect(&ncm,SIGNAL(updateCompleted()),this,SLOT(configurationsUpdateCompleted()));
    QNetworkConfiguration nc;
    QList<QNetworkConfiguration> configs = ncm.allConfigurations(QNetworkConfiguration::Active);
    qDebug() << "\nAllConfigs: ";
    foreach (nc,configs)
    {
        qDebug() << nc.identifier() << nc.name() << nc.state();
    }
    QString MAC = filterMAC(configs);
    qDebug() << "\nMAC:" << MAC;
    if(MAC.isEmpty())
    {
        qDebug("no MAC address found");
    }
    emit foundMAC(MAC);
}
```

Comment: Maybe other windows firewall blocked your app.   add it to firewall list , https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/uncategorized/how-to-create-exceptions-in-windows-vista-firewall/

Comment: I'm not sending or receiving any packets

Comment: can you pack your project (exe file + dll) and upload it some where to download it.

Comment: Debug it. Add a bunch of logging so that you can see the execution path, return values of function calls etc.

Comment: I've uploaded the files the link is: https://ufile.io/e9htu

Comment: @DrEval there are lots of debug lines and anything that we can get our hands on are there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded your app and analyze it on my computer.

problem is you missing some dlls, your app running without error but not working properly. (`qgenericbearer.dll` , `qnativewifibearer.dll` with folder `bearer` are missing ).

you can use windeploy command to deploy your project.

go to Qt, compiler directory on your OS for example:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2013\bin
```

[image: Screenshot1]

press `Shift+right click mouse` then `click open command window here`

type windeployqt.exe c:\Your app directory for example:

```
windeployqt.exe C:\Users\Mofrad\Downloads\macfindertest\macFinderTest\macAddressTest.exe
```

[image: Screenshot2]

now some dlls will copy to your app directory.

Now try your app again and you'll see it's working.