# Xcopy files to the new directory in pro/pri file

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmake

how can I copy the entire directory with the contents to new path using pro file.
I tried "xcopy /S /I /Y" but its not working. Can someone point the error I am doing

```
    BINARY_DESTINATION_PATH = $$PWD$$SEPARATOR/dd/
    RESOURCE_SOURCE_PATH = $$PWD$$SEPARATOR/temp

    EXPORTED_DESTINATION_PATH = $${BINARY_DESTINATION_PATH}
    EXPORTED_DESTINATION_PATH ~= s,/,\\,g

    EXPORTED_SOURCE_PATH = $${RESOURCE_SOURCE_PATH}
    EXPORTED_SOURCE_PATH ~= s,/,\\,g

    QT += core
    QT -= gui

    CONFIG += c++11

    TARGET = sample
    CONFIG += console
    CONFIG -= app_bundle

    TEMPLATE = app

    SOURCES += main.cpp

    win32 {
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cmd /c xcopy /S /I /Y $${EXPORTED_SOURCE_PATH}\\copy_to_output $${EXPORTED_DESTINATION_PATH})
    }
```

Comment: It's better to use pri file to do that

Comment: OKe, is it something like pro file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358627/qt-pro-vs-pri

Comment: I created a new PRI file in current directory and moved the line xcopy there, but its not giving any effect

Comment: check my below answer and read the links in my post. -   project should be on Release mode and don't forget include `.pri` file in `.pro` file like this: `#win32: include(folderName/fileName.pri)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you looking for Qt deployment tool.

[Deploying Qt Applications](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html): Deploying a Qt application does not require any C++ programming. All you need to do is to build Qt and your application in release mode, following the procedures described in this documentation.

More info for deploying applications in windows [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html).

[The Windows Deployment Tool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html):
The Windows deployment tool is designed to automate the process of creating a deployable folder containing the Qt-related dependencies (libraries, QML imports, plugins, and translations) required to run the application from that folder.

Also check my answer about Windeploy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45531369/5068056

I explain it completely with screenshots.