# How to deploy a directory to a remote device using Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, deployment, directory, qml

I want to deploy some js files and qml files to the remote device in addition to the executable. The TARGET keyword works good for executable but how can I deploy other files? I thought of having all of them in a directory and deploy it but I have no idea.

Comment: Maybe adding a custom step `make install` helps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45531369/5068056